# Problems with TableView inside of ScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I followed the helpful comments by you people and have currently gotten this far: I have a single TableView with a header cell. The problem now is that I am only able to display one set of data and the TableView will not currently scroll (Maybe because of only one set of data being displayed.)

Here is my Code:

ViewController:

```js
    struct TableData {

        var section: String = ""
        
        var data = Array<String>()
        
        var dataS = Array<String>()
        
        init(){}

    }

    var data = Array<TableData>()
    var dataS = Array<TableData>()

    class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet var labelS: UILabel!
        
    }

    class MyCustomHeader: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var header: UILabel!
        
    }

    class TypeViewController: BaseViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
        
        @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
            return data[section].data.count
        
        }
        
        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
            
            cell.label.text = data[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]
            cell.labelS.text = dataS[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]
            
            return cell

           
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            
            let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Header") as! MyCustomHeader
            
            headerCell.header.text = data[section].section
            
            return headerCell

        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 50.0
        }
        
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addSlideMenuButton()
            addItems()
            
            print(data)
            
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
        
func addItems() {

        var new_elements:TableData

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Stuff"
        new_elements.data.append(obj41);
        new_elements.data.append(obj42);
        new_elements.data.append(obj43);
        new_elements.data.append(obj44);
        new_elements.data.append(obj45);
        new_elements.data.append(obj46);
        new_elements.data.append(obj47);
        
        data.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "More Stuff"
        new_elements.data.append(obj51);
        new_elements.data.append(obj52);
        new_elements.data.append(obj53);
        new_elements.data.append(obj54);
        new_elements.data.append(obj55);
        new_elements.data.append(obj56);
        new_elements.data.append(obj57);
        
        data.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Netzach - Eternity"
        new_elements.data.append(obj61);
        new_elements.data.append(obj62);
        new_elements.data.append(obj63);
        new_elements.data.append(obj64);
        new_elements.data.append(obj65);
        new_elements.data.append(obj66);
        new_elements.data.append(obj67);
        
        data.append(new_elements)
        
        //Break
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.data.append(objS0);
        new_elements.data.append(objS1);
        new_elements.data.append(objS2);
        new_elements.data.append(objS3);
        new_elements.data.append(objS4);
        new_elements.data.append(objS5);
        new_elements.data.append(objS6);
        new_elements.data.append(objS7);
        
        dataS.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.data.append(objS11);
        new_elements.data.append(objS12);
        new_elements.data.append(objS13);
        new_elements.data.append(objS14);
        new_elements.data.append(objS15);
        new_elements.data.append(objS16);
        new_elements.data.append(objS17);
        
        dataS.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.data.append(objS21);
        new_elements.data.append(objS22);
        new_elements.data.append(objS23);
        new_elements.data.append(objS24);
        new_elements.data.append(objS25);
        new_elements.data.append(objS26);
        new_elements.data.append(objS27);
        
        dataS.append(new_elements)
}
```

Attached are some Photos of the MainStoryboard:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the issue ? What you are trying to do ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html

Go through this artical .... same direction nested scrolling is supported

Comment: Edit your question in proper format. and add your prototype cell screen shot.

Comment: Why you compare  tableview like,"tableView.tag == typeView.tag".you can compare directly "tableView == typeView" .

Comment: did u bind delegate? and delegate methods are called?

Comment: A table view IS a scroll view. Don't put it inside another one. That's just stupid!

Comment: But then how do I make the page scroll without putting the TableView inside of the ScrollView. And BTW, I do already know that TableViews inherit from ScrollViews. Any ideas on how I can make the page scroll while having a TableView inside of it. I already disabled scrolling on the TableView but then the ScrollView won't scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind below important points regarding to `UITableView`

1. `UITableView` has inherited property from `UIScrollView` i.e. `UITableView` is also below like a `UIScrollView` so you don't need to take `UIScrollView` for the specially scroll the `UITableView`. If you do it behaves weird.
2. In `cellForRow`, you are creating condition with param `tableView` to outlet `typeView` & `typeView1` by comparing tag which is not a standard format. Because `tableView.tag` may be changed and gives you wrong output. So try to use below format

   `if tableView == typeView { }
    else  { } //tableView == typeView1`

   Compare `UITableView` objects with pram `tableView`.
3. `cellForRow` method returns the `cell` from the `if-else` so you don't need to write

`return UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")`

If I debug your `cellForRow` method code then your this above line never executes.

**First try this standards and remove your mistake and then post your question and issue you are facing.**

Hope my above work helps you.

> Edit

Your required output will be like this below image. You don't need to take 2 `UItableView` and thse `tableview` in single `scrollview`. You can do the same with one `tableView`.

[image]

Go through this [tutorial](http://www.kaleidosblog.com/uitableview-custom-cell-how-to-define-a-custom-cell-with-swift-in-ios)

Comment: for point 3: maybe the compiler say that the `if-else if` (not `if-else`) can not satisfied for all possibilities and thats why he need to add a return statement if the `tableView.tag` is not `typeView.tag` and not `typeView1.tag`

Comment: No bro in last of if-else there always will be else so put your last condition there.

Comment: That's right if there where only an `if-else`. But please look at code. There in this line `} else if tableView.tag == typeView1.tag {` is no `if-else` - there is an `if - else if`

Comment: I am still having the problem. I can't make my ScrollView scroll.

Comment: @muescha check my code also. there is only two possibility either `tableview` is of type1 or it of type2. And check specially, what does `tableview` returns for ` UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. Does it mean anything?? I don't think so. Its ok it returns the cell what about the cell data?? You have to create object of your custom class and use it.

Comment: @kps2501 what problem you are facing pls mention.

Comment: My problem is that I want a stationary TableView that does not scroll and I want that to be inside a ScrollView. If you want to see a video of this being done in Android I can send you that. I am actually much better with Android then I am with iOS otherwise I know how to fix this in Android. Thanks

Comment: @kps2501 Actually your approach is wrong. Send me that video that you are talking about.

Comment: with your code yes - you don't need it, because you use `if-else` (after your have done an edit of your original answer. before the edit you used also the `if - else if` but you forget to put the `if` to your code `else tableView == typeView1 { }`. also the original code with with `if - else if` need this code part

Comment: @muescha I wanted this to write in comment to describe which code is to write in else part. so i edit my answer so pls check again. If there still any mistake then ask. Thanks.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy Do you get what I want? I want a scroll view which contains labels and table views (Table Views don't scroll). Can you send me example code to do this? I would really appreciate it. I will try to send you the android video soon.

Comment: So I get the TableViews to work, the only problem is that my scrollView won't scroll unless I have Bounce Vertically on, I don't want my scrollView to bounce vertically.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy So the Ui is already done, I just want the ScrollView as shown in the video to scroll. Can you please help me with that

Comment: Thanks so much @the_dahiya_boy you made my day! I will try this tomorrow. Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy it still doesn't work. ;(. I still can't get my TableView to scroll without also making it bounce. Also, my tableView only shows one set of items. Do you want me to send you the files to my app so that you can fix it?